# How packages that does not contain executables actually works?

Tags: installer, file-types, installation-package

**How do installers that contains only files like (`.rsrc_1`, `[0]`, `.rdata` etc.) actually work?**

Example:
[image: Example]

For comparison:

I can imagine how installers that contains files like `.msi`, `.cab` work - they extract themself somewhere and initiate installation.

Example:
[image: Example]

Comment: The assumption that instead of running the setup.exe you can extract it and then run those files is *wrong*. Setup exes are not made for extracting them using tools like 7zip. 7zip just tries its best and it will work more or less well.

Answer (score 2):

#### How do installers that contains only files like (.rsrc_1, [0], .rdata etc.) actually work?

Your second example is a self-extracting exe file.

The first example is an ordinary exe file. The code to be executed is in the `.text` section.

For more information see [windows - what's in a .exe file? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495638/whats-in-a-exe-file)

Comment: That's correct. Also see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment

Answer (score 1):

Because it *is* an executable.

Just because you can open it in 7-zip does not mean that it is "just" an archive. What you are opening is an executable that knows how to extract its own payload from the `[0]` data blob.

Some "programs" such as your nvidia installer are essentially zip files with a self-extracting executable stuck in front of it. 7zip can see a small executable with a large amount of data after it, has a look at that data and sees a normal archive that it can open. Then you get to see the main data.

Others, such as the Samsung installer, are real executables where the payload has been inserted into a data section within an executable. It needs some special processing to extract it from the executable file and that is done when the executable runs. It might be some special compression method that 7-zip doesn't know about.